# JS code works on Firefox but not on Chrome or Edge

Tags: javascript

It's little bit strange why the code is running smoothly on FireFox but not on Chrome and Edge. I know that a lot of the code is repeating(It's for the snippet),however the main problem is with the stationid field:

```
 <input type="number" id="stationId" name="stationid" />
```

When I select Line: 623-1 and choose any position, in the stationid field the value should be inserted, this works in Firefox as I said. What can cause such misbehavior?

This is the function where the magic happens:

```
function CreateOption(position, stationId) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = stationId;
    newOption.innerText = position;
    chosenPosition.appendChild(newOption);

    newOption.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("stationId").value = parseInt(stationId);
    })
}
```

I'm out of ideas what can cause the issue, please if anyone is familiar with similar problem share your thoughts. Thank you in advance!

```js
function Station(stationid, line, position) {
    this.stationid = stationid;
    this.line = line;
    this.position = position
}

let stations = [];

var stationOne = new Station();
stationOne.stationid = 1;
stationOne.line = "623-1";
stationOne.position = "1300";

var stationTwo = new Station();
stationTwo.stationid = 2;
stationTwo.line = "623-1";
stationTwo.position = "2000";

var stationThree = new Station();
stationThree.stationid = 3;
stationThree.line = "623-1";
stationThree.position = "2200";

var stationFour = new Station();
stationFour.stationid = 4;
stationFour.line = "623-1";
stationFour.position = "2300";

var stationFive = new Station();
stationFive.stationid = 5;
stationFive.line = "623-1";
stationFive.position = "2400";

var stationSix = new Station();
stationSix.stationid = 6;
stationSix.line = "623-1";
stationSix.position = "2600";

var stationSeven = new Station();
stationSeven.stationid = 7;
stationSeven.line = "623-1";
stationSeven.position = "2800";

var stationEight = new Station();
stationEight.stationid = 8;
stationEight.line = "623-1";
stationEight.position = "2900";

var stationNine = new Station();
stationNine.stationid = 9;
stationNine.line = "623-1";
stationNine.position = "3000";

var stationTen = new Station();
stationTen.stationid = 10;
stationTen.line = "623-1";
stationTen.position = "3200";

var stationEleven = new Station();
stationEleven.stationid = 11;
stationEleven.line = "623-2";
stationEleven.position = "1300";

var stationTwelve = new Station();
stationTwelve.stationid = 12;
stationTwelve.line = "623-2";
stationTwelve.position = "1300";

var stationThirteen = new Station();
stationThirteen.stationid = 13;
stationThirteen.line = "623-2";
stationThirteen.position = "2000";

var stationFourteen = new Station();
stationFourteen.stationid = 14;
stationFourteen.line = "623-2";
stationFourteen.position = "2200";

var stationFifteen = new Station();
stationFifteen.stationid = 15;
stationFifteen.line = "623-2";
stationFifteen.position = "2300";

var stationSixteen = new Station();
stationSixteen.stationid = 16;
stationSixteen.line = "623-2";
stationSixteen.position = "2400";

var stationSeventeen = new Station();
stationSeventeen.stationid = 17;
stationSeventeen.line = "623-2";
stationSeventeen.position = "2600";

var stationEighteen = new Station();
stationEighteen.stationid = 18;
stationEighteen.line = "623-2";
stationEighteen.position = "2800";

var stationNineteen = new Station();
stationNineteen.stationid = 19;
stationNineteen.line = "623-2";
stationNineteen.position = "2900";

var stationTwenty = new Station();
stationTwenty.stationid = 20;
stationTwenty.line = "623-2";
stationTwenty.position = "3000";

var stationTwentyOne = new Station();
stationTwentyOne.stationid = 21;
stationTwentyOne.line = "623-2";
stationTwentyOne.position = "3200";

var stationTwentyTwo = new Station();
stationTwentyTwo.stationid = 22;
stationTwentyTwo.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyTwo.position = "1300";

var stationTwentyThree = new Station();
stationTwentyThree.stationid = 23;
stationTwentyThree.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyThree.position = "2000";

var stationTwentyFour = new Station();
stationTwentyFour.stationid = 24;
stationTwentyFour.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyFour.position = "2200";

var stationTwentyFive = new Station();
stationTwentyFive.stationid = 25;
stationTwentyFive.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyFive.position = "2300";

var stationTwentySix = new Station();
stationTwentySix.stationid = 26;
stationTwentySix.line = "623-3";
stationTwentySix.position = "2400";

var stationTwentySeven = new Station();
stationTwentySeven.stationid = 27;
stationTwentySeven.line = "623-3";
stationTwentySeven.position = "2600";

var stationTwentyEight = new Station();
stationTwentyEight.stationid = 28;
stationTwentyEight.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyEight.position = "2800";

var stationTwentyNine = new Station();
stationTwentyNine.stationid = 29;
stationTwentyNine.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyNine.position = "2900";

var stationThirty = new Station();
stationThirty.stationid = 30;
stationThirty.line = "623-3";
stationThirty.position = "3000";

var stationThirtyOne = new Station();
stationThirtyOne.stationid = 31;
stationThirtyOne.line = "623-3";
stationThirtyOne.position = "3200";

var stationThirtyTwo = new Station();
stationThirtyTwo.stationid = 32;
stationThirtyTwo.line = "626";
stationThirtyTwo.position = "1600";

var stationThirtyThree = new Station();
stationThirtyThree.stationid = 33;
stationThirtyThree.line = "626";
stationThirtyThree.position = "2000";

var stationThirtyFour = new Station();
stationThirtyFour.stationid = 34;
stationThirtyFour.line = "626";
stationThirtyFour.position = "2100";

var stationThirtyFive = new Station();
stationThirtyFive.stationid = 35;
stationThirtyFive.line = "626";
stationThirtyFive.position = "2300";

var stationThirtySix = new Station();
stationThirtySix.stationid = 36;
stationThirtySix.line = "626";
stationThirtySix.position = "2800";

var stationThirtySeven = new Station();
stationThirtySeven.stationid = 37;
stationThirtySeven.line = "626";
stationThirtySeven.position = "2900";

var stationThirtyEight = new Station();
stationThirtyEight.stationid = 38;
stationThirtyEight.line = "626";
stationThirtyEight.position = "3000";

var stationThirtyNine = new Station();
stationThirtyNine.stationid = 39;
stationThirtyNine.line = "626";
stationThirtyNine.position = "3200";

var stationFourty = new Station();
stationFourty.stationid = 40;
stationFourty.line = "628";
stationFourty.position = "1300";

var stationFourtyOne = new Station();
stationFourtyOne.stationid = 41;
stationFourtyOne.line = "628";
stationFourtyOne.position = "1400";

var stationFourtyTwo = new Station();
stationFourtyTwo.stationid = 42;
stationFourtyTwo.line = "628";
stationFourtyTwo.position = "1450";

var stationFourtyThree = new Station();
stationFourtyThree.stationid = 43;
stationFourtyThree.line = "628";
stationFourtyThree.position = "1500";

var stationFourtyFour = new Station();
stationFourtyFour.stationid = 44;
stationFourtyFour.line = "628";
stationFourtyFour.position = "2000";

var stationFourtyFive = new Station();
stationFourtyFive.stationid = 45;
stationFourtyFive.line = "628";
stationFourtyFive.position = "3000";

var stationFourtySix = new Station();
stationFourtySix.stationid = 46;
stationFourtySix.line = "628";
stationFourtySix.position = "3200";

stations.push(stationOne);
stations.push(stationTwo);
stations.push(stationThree);
stations.push(stationFour);
stations.push(stationFive);
stations.push(stationSix);
stations.push(stationSeven);
stations.push(stationEight);
stations.push(stationNine);
stations.push(stationTen);
stations.push(stationEleven);
stations.push(stationTwelve);
stations.push(stationThirteen);
stations.push(stationFourteen);
stations.push(stationFifteen);
stations.push(stationSixteen);
stations.push(stationSeventeen);
stations.push(stationEighteen);
stations.push(stationNineteen);
stations.push(stationTwenty);
stations.push(stationTwentyOne);
stations.push(stationTwentyTwo);
stations.push(stationTwentyThree);
stations.push(stationTwentyFour);
stations.push(stationTwentyFive);
stations.push(stationTwentySix);
stations.push(stationTwentySeven);
stations.push(stationTwentyEight);
stations.push(stationTwentyNine);
stations.push(stationThirty);
stations.push(stationThirtyOne);
stations.push(stationThirtyTwo);
stations.push(stationThirtyThree);
stations.push(stationThirtyFour);
stations.push(stationThirtyFive);
stations.push(stationThirtySix);
stations.push(stationThirtySeven);
stations.push(stationThirtyEight);
stations.push(stationThirtyNine);
stations.push(stationFourty);
stations.push(stationFourtyOne);
stations.push(stationFourtyTwo);
stations.push(stationFourtyThree);
stations.push(stationFourtyFour);
stations.push(stationFourtyFive);
stations.push(stationFourtySix);

let chosenPosition = document.getElementById("chosen-position");

document.getElementById('chosen-line').addEventListener('change', function () {

    switch (this.value) {
        case "622-3":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-3");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-4":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-4");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-5":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-5");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-6":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-6");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-7":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-7");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-8":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-8");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-9":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-9");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "623-1":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "623-1");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "623-2":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "623-2");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "623-3":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "623-3");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "626":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "626");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "628":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "628");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        default:
            ClearPositions();
            break;
    }
});
function CreateOption(position, stationId) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = stationId;
    newOption.innerText = position;
    chosenPosition.appendChild(newOption);

    newOption.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("stationId").value = parseInt(stationId);
    })
}
function CreateDefaultOption() {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = "";
    newOption.innerText = "Please select position";
    newOption.disabled;
    chosenPosition.appendChild(newOption);

}
function ClearPositions() {
    document.getElementById("chosen-position").innerText = "";
}
```

```html
            <form asp-controller="Quality" asp-action="Select" method="POST">
                <label>Choose a line
                    <select id="chosen-line" name="line" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Line</option>
                        <option value="622-3">622-3</option>
                        <option value="622-4">622-4</option>
                        <option value="622-5">622-5</option>
                        <option value="626-3">622-6</option>
                        <option value="622-7">622-7</option>
                        <option value="622-8">622-8</option>
                        <option value="622-9">622-9</option>
                        <option value="623-1">623-1</option>
                        <option value="623-2">623-2</option>
                        <option value="623-3">623-3</option>
                        <option value="626">626</option>
                        <option value="628">628</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label>Choose position
                    <select id="chosen-position" name="position" required>
                       <option value="" disabled selected>Select position</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="stationId" name="stationid" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn-create" id="btn-next">Next</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Wow. Please be DRY (don't repeat yourself) - your code could be a 10th of the size. So much code to look through

Comment: mplungjan I know a lot of code is repeating at the moment.  For testing purpose, choose a line: 623-1, then position: 2200. So when you select the position in stationid field the value should be inserted. And no, it's not working on Chrome, only on Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not help refactoring this saving 342 lines of code ;) - more if you move the array to a separate file

Note the first select are unique "line" values from the stations

```js
const chosenLine = document.getElementById('chosen-line');
const stationId = document.getElementById("stationId");
const chosenPosition = document.getElementById("chosen-position");

chosenPosition.addEventListener("change",function() {
  stationId.value = this.value;
})

chosenLine.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const val = this.value;
  chosenPosition.options.length = 1; // clear all but first entry
  const options = stations
    .filter((x, i) => { x.index = i; return x.line === val })
    .map(({ position, index }) => `<option value="${index}">${position}</option>`)
  chosenPosition.innerHTML += options.join("");
})

const stations = [
{ line: "623-1", position: "1300" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "2000" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "2200" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "2300" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "2400" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "2600" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "2800" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "2900" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "3000" }, 
{ line: "623-1", position: "3200" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "1300" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "1300" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "2000" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "2200" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "2300" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "2400" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "2600" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "2800" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "2900" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "3000" }, 
{ line: "623-2", position: "3200" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "1300" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "2000" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "2200" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "2300" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "2400" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "2600" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "2800" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "2900" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "3000" }, 
{ line: "623-3", position: "3200" }, 
{ line: "626",   position: "1600" }, 
{ line: "626",   position: "2000" }, 
{ line: "626",   position: "2100" }, 
{ line: "626",   position: "2300" }, 
{ line: "626",   position: "2800" }, 
{ line: "626",   position: "2900" }, 
{ line: "626",   position: "3000" }, 
{ line: "626",   position: "3200" }, 
{ line: "628",   position: "1300" }, 
{ line: "628",   position: "1400" }, 
{ line: "628",   position: "1450" }, 
{ line: "628",   position: "1500" }, 
{ line: "628",   position: "2000" }, 
{ line: "628",   position: "3000" }, 
{ line: "628",   position: "3200" }];

chosenLine.innerHTML += [...new Set(stations.map(({line}) => line))] // create unique items
  .map(item => `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`)
  .join("")
```

```html
<form asp-controller="Quality" asp-action="Select" method="POST">
  <label>Choose a line
    <select id="chosen-line" name="line" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Line</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Choose position
    <select id="chosen-position" name="position" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select position</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="stationId" name="stationid" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn-create" id="btn-next">Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan!! much appreciated, I just refactored the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `click` events on `option` elements in a `select` doesn't work reliably cross-browser. Instead, use the `change` event on the `select` itself, and use the `selectedIndex`, `value`, or `selectedOptions` properties to know what options have been chosen.

For instance:

```
chosenPosition.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;
    console.log(`Value chosen: ${value}`);
    if (value) {
        document.getElementById("stationId").value = parseInt(value, 10); // *** Always use the second argument
    }
});
```

Then remove the code adding an event handler on the `option` elements.

Example:

```js
function Station(stationid, line, position) {
    this.stationid = stationid;
    this.line = line;
    this.position = position
}

let stations = [];

var stationOne = new Station();
stationOne.stationid = 1;
stationOne.line = "623-1";
stationOne.position = "1300";

var stationTwo = new Station();
stationTwo.stationid = 2;
stationTwo.line = "623-1";
stationTwo.position = "2000";

var stationThree = new Station();
stationThree.stationid = 3;
stationThree.line = "623-1";
stationThree.position = "2200";

var stationFour = new Station();
stationFour.stationid = 4;
stationFour.line = "623-1";
stationFour.position = "2300";

var stationFive = new Station();
stationFive.stationid = 5;
stationFive.line = "623-1";
stationFive.position = "2400";

var stationSix = new Station();
stationSix.stationid = 6;
stationSix.line = "623-1";
stationSix.position = "2600";

var stationSeven = new Station();
stationSeven.stationid = 7;
stationSeven.line = "623-1";
stationSeven.position = "2800";

var stationEight = new Station();
stationEight.stationid = 8;
stationEight.line = "623-1";
stationEight.position = "2900";

var stationNine = new Station();
stationNine.stationid = 9;
stationNine.line = "623-1";
stationNine.position = "3000";

var stationTen = new Station();
stationTen.stationid = 10;
stationTen.line = "623-1";
stationTen.position = "3200";

var stationEleven = new Station();
stationEleven.stationid = 11;
stationEleven.line = "623-2";
stationEleven.position = "1300";

var stationTwelve = new Station();
stationTwelve.stationid = 12;
stationTwelve.line = "623-2";
stationTwelve.position = "1300";

var stationThirteen = new Station();
stationThirteen.stationid = 13;
stationThirteen.line = "623-2";
stationThirteen.position = "2000";

var stationFourteen = new Station();
stationFourteen.stationid = 14;
stationFourteen.line = "623-2";
stationFourteen.position = "2200";

var stationFifteen = new Station();
stationFifteen.stationid = 15;
stationFifteen.line = "623-2";
stationFifteen.position = "2300";

var stationSixteen = new Station();
stationSixteen.stationid = 16;
stationSixteen.line = "623-2";
stationSixteen.position = "2400";

var stationSeventeen = new Station();
stationSeventeen.stationid = 17;
stationSeventeen.line = "623-2";
stationSeventeen.position = "2600";

var stationEighteen = new Station();
stationEighteen.stationid = 18;
stationEighteen.line = "623-2";
stationEighteen.position = "2800";

var stationNineteen = new Station();
stationNineteen.stationid = 19;
stationNineteen.line = "623-2";
stationNineteen.position = "2900";

var stationTwenty = new Station();
stationTwenty.stationid = 20;
stationTwenty.line = "623-2";
stationTwenty.position = "3000";

var stationTwentyOne = new Station();
stationTwentyOne.stationid = 21;
stationTwentyOne.line = "623-2";
stationTwentyOne.position = "3200";

var stationTwentyTwo = new Station();
stationTwentyTwo.stationid = 22;
stationTwentyTwo.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyTwo.position = "1300";

var stationTwentyThree = new Station();
stationTwentyThree.stationid = 23;
stationTwentyThree.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyThree.position = "2000";

var stationTwentyFour = new Station();
stationTwentyFour.stationid = 24;
stationTwentyFour.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyFour.position = "2200";

var stationTwentyFive = new Station();
stationTwentyFive.stationid = 25;
stationTwentyFive.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyFive.position = "2300";

var stationTwentySix = new Station();
stationTwentySix.stationid = 26;
stationTwentySix.line = "623-3";
stationTwentySix.position = "2400";

var stationTwentySeven = new Station();
stationTwentySeven.stationid = 27;
stationTwentySeven.line = "623-3";
stationTwentySeven.position = "2600";

var stationTwentyEight = new Station();
stationTwentyEight.stationid = 28;
stationTwentyEight.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyEight.position = "2800";

var stationTwentyNine = new Station();
stationTwentyNine.stationid = 29;
stationTwentyNine.line = "623-3";
stationTwentyNine.position = "2900";

var stationThirty = new Station();
stationThirty.stationid = 30;
stationThirty.line = "623-3";
stationThirty.position = "3000";

var stationThirtyOne = new Station();
stationThirtyOne.stationid = 31;
stationThirtyOne.line = "623-3";
stationThirtyOne.position = "3200";

var stationThirtyTwo = new Station();
stationThirtyTwo.stationid = 32;
stationThirtyTwo.line = "626";
stationThirtyTwo.position = "1600";

var stationThirtyThree = new Station();
stationThirtyThree.stationid = 33;
stationThirtyThree.line = "626";
stationThirtyThree.position = "2000";

var stationThirtyFour = new Station();
stationThirtyFour.stationid = 34;
stationThirtyFour.line = "626";
stationThirtyFour.position = "2100";

var stationThirtyFive = new Station();
stationThirtyFive.stationid = 35;
stationThirtyFive.line = "626";
stationThirtyFive.position = "2300";

var stationThirtySix = new Station();
stationThirtySix.stationid = 36;
stationThirtySix.line = "626";
stationThirtySix.position = "2800";

var stationThirtySeven = new Station();
stationThirtySeven.stationid = 37;
stationThirtySeven.line = "626";
stationThirtySeven.position = "2900";

var stationThirtyEight = new Station();
stationThirtyEight.stationid = 38;
stationThirtyEight.line = "626";
stationThirtyEight.position = "3000";

var stationThirtyNine = new Station();
stationThirtyNine.stationid = 39;
stationThirtyNine.line = "626";
stationThirtyNine.position = "3200";

var stationFourty = new Station();
stationFourty.stationid = 40;
stationFourty.line = "628";
stationFourty.position = "1300";

var stationFourtyOne = new Station();
stationFourtyOne.stationid = 41;
stationFourtyOne.line = "628";
stationFourtyOne.position = "1400";

var stationFourtyTwo = new Station();
stationFourtyTwo.stationid = 42;
stationFourtyTwo.line = "628";
stationFourtyTwo.position = "1450";

var stationFourtyThree = new Station();
stationFourtyThree.stationid = 43;
stationFourtyThree.line = "628";
stationFourtyThree.position = "1500";

var stationFourtyFour = new Station();
stationFourtyFour.stationid = 44;
stationFourtyFour.line = "628";
stationFourtyFour.position = "2000";

var stationFourtyFive = new Station();
stationFourtyFive.stationid = 45;
stationFourtyFive.line = "628";
stationFourtyFive.position = "3000";

var stationFourtySix = new Station();
stationFourtySix.stationid = 46;
stationFourtySix.line = "628";
stationFourtySix.position = "3200";

stations.push(stationOne);
stations.push(stationTwo);
stations.push(stationThree);
stations.push(stationFour);
stations.push(stationFive);
stations.push(stationSix);
stations.push(stationSeven);
stations.push(stationEight);
stations.push(stationNine);
stations.push(stationTen);
stations.push(stationEleven);
stations.push(stationTwelve);
stations.push(stationThirteen);
stations.push(stationFourteen);
stations.push(stationFifteen);
stations.push(stationSixteen);
stations.push(stationSeventeen);
stations.push(stationEighteen);
stations.push(stationNineteen);
stations.push(stationTwenty);
stations.push(stationTwentyOne);
stations.push(stationTwentyTwo);
stations.push(stationTwentyThree);
stations.push(stationTwentyFour);
stations.push(stationTwentyFive);
stations.push(stationTwentySix);
stations.push(stationTwentySeven);
stations.push(stationTwentyEight);
stations.push(stationTwentyNine);
stations.push(stationThirty);
stations.push(stationThirtyOne);
stations.push(stationThirtyTwo);
stations.push(stationThirtyThree);
stations.push(stationThirtyFour);
stations.push(stationThirtyFive);
stations.push(stationThirtySix);
stations.push(stationThirtySeven);
stations.push(stationThirtyEight);
stations.push(stationThirtyNine);
stations.push(stationFourty);
stations.push(stationFourtyOne);
stations.push(stationFourtyTwo);
stations.push(stationFourtyThree);
stations.push(stationFourtyFour);
stations.push(stationFourtyFive);
stations.push(stationFourtySix);

let chosenPosition = document.getElementById("chosen-position");
chosenPosition.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;
    console.log(`Value chosen: ${value}`);
    if (value) {
        document.getElementById("stationId").value = parseInt(value, 10); // *** Always use the second argument
    }
});

document.getElementById('chosen-line').addEventListener('change', function () {

    switch (this.value) {
        case "622-3":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-3");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-4":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-4");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-5":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-5");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-6":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-6");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-7":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-7");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-8":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-8");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "622-9":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "622-9");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "623-1":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "623-1");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "623-2":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "623-2");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "623-3":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "623-3");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "626":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "626");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        case "628":
            ClearPositions();
            CreateDefaultOption();
            var filtered = stations.filter(x => x.line == "628");
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                CreateOption(filtered[i].position, filtered[i].stationid);
            }
            break;
        default:
            ClearPositions();
            break;
    }
});
function CreateOption(position, stationId) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = stationId;
    newOption.innerText = position;
    chosenPosition.appendChild(newOption);

    /*
    newOption.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("stationId").value = parseInt(stationId);
    })
    */
}
function CreateDefaultOption() {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = "";
    newOption.innerText = "Please select position";
    newOption.disabled;
    chosenPosition.appendChild(newOption);

}
function ClearPositions() {
    document.getElementById("chosen-position").innerText = "";
}
```

```html
<form asp-controller="Quality" asp-action="Select" method="POST">
                <label>Choose a line
                    <select id="chosen-line" name="line" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Line</option>
                        <option value="622-3">622-3</option>
                        <option value="622-4">622-4</option>
                        <option value="622-5">622-5</option>
                        <option value="626-3">622-6</option>
                        <option value="622-7">622-7</option>
                        <option value="622-8">622-8</option>
                        <option value="622-9">622-9</option>
                        <option value="623-1">623-1</option>
                        <option value="623-2">623-2</option>
                        <option value="623-3">623-3</option>
                        <option value="626">626</option>
                        <option value="628">628</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label>Choose position
                    <select id="chosen-position" name="position" required>
                       <option value="" disabled selected>Select position</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="stationId" name="stationid" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn-create" id="btn-next">Next</button>
            </form>
```

---

I didn't do a code review or anything, but a few things stood out:

1. You may want to use the `Option` constructor rather than `createElement` followed by assigning to `value` and `innerText`. For instance, instead of:

   ```
   var newOption = document.createElement("option");
   newOption.value = stationId;
   newOption.innerText = position;
   ```

   you can do:

   ```
   var newOption = new Option(position, stationId);
   ```
2. This line of code doesn't do anything useful:

   ```
   newOption.disabled;
   ```

   If you meant to disable the "Please select position" element, you'd need:

   ```
   newOption.disabled = true;
   ```
3. As mplungjan said, that code can be reduced to be much more readable and maintainable. For example, the 278 lines creating the `stations` array can be replaced with 49 lines (46 stations plus three lines of overhead) like this:

   ```
   let nextId = 1;
   let stations = [
       new Station(nextId++, "623-1", "1300"),
       new Station(nextId++, "623-1", "2000"),
       new Station(nextId++, "623-1", "2200"),
       new Station(nextId++, "623-1", "2200"),
       // ...and so on...
   ];
   ```

   Your `Station` constructor already accepts the parameters and assigns to the properties (but if not, we could easily have modified it or written a wrapper function).

Comment: T.J. Crowder, thousands times thank you! I don't use frequently JS, but I will refactor the code now. I owe you a beer and thank you again!!!